# Generating specific request cookies for a website

Tags: javascript

I have a script that autocheckouts products on a website (bot), recently the site seemed to update something and I keep getting 403 blocks(Perimeter X). My old solution was simply to rotate and brute force with unblocked proxies but now with proxies working fine in my browser I cannot get the proper request cookies sorted out to get a response (Checkout flow).

Any methods to try and be able to access the request cookies? Or must I locate the site scripts and try and generate them there? Thanks in advance